# Resize canvas based on number of canvas wrt to parent div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

I have a viewport of a certain dimension. Currently, i was showing only a single image which is drawn on a html5 canvas. But now i need to show multiple canvas which could range from 1-6. 
The requirement is to resize the canvases based on the number of canvas so that it fits into the parent div.

For example : Single canvas should take 100% of the parent div, 2 canvas 50-50%. So for 6 canvas it would be 2 rows with 3 canvas each.

Also, user can toggle show/hide of certain canvas so they will have to rearrange.

How can i go about doing this? I am using angularjs ,javascript and html5 css3.

Comment: Show what you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

**Check out CSS Flexbox** which can auto-size and auto-arrange your multiple canvases inside a container div.

- CSS-Tricks has an excellent [overview of Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- Wes Bos has done a very nice series of [video tutorials of Flexbox](http://flexbox.io/view/qBvW8KC9bb4)

Flexbox is easy to use after a small learning curve.

Declare your div as a Flexbox container:

```
#theDiv{ display: flex; }
```

And then tell Flexbox how you want your canvas-items displayed:

```
#theDiv{ flex-flow: row wrap; }
```

You haven't detailed how you want the canvases to grow / shrink when the container div is resized or when the user hides / shows canvases, but Flexbox has grow / shrink settings that you can apply to all canvas-items and even to specific canvas(s).

Comment: I am trying to avoid any third party libraries or plugins. just using css and javascript/angularjs i would like to achieve this functionality. And yes i want the canvases to grow/shrink based on hide/show of canvas. The container div remains the same size.

Comment: Flexbox is pure CSS! :-))